# Can I umount root '/' to make an iso file of root partition?

Tags: boot, mount, backup, dd

I have Ubuntu installed on `/dev/sda1` and an external USB disk mounted in `/mnt/backup`.

I want to make an `iso` file of my `/dev/sda` hard-disk, and for this I planned to use

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/backup/hd.iso $option
```

I can't boot from external devices, so I was wondering if there is an option to `umount` the partition currently mounted in `/`, or make it read-only, so that `dd` will store a consistent state of the disk.

Comment: There is no such command obviously.

Comment: And you should do it from a live session, not from the running system

Comment: Maybe you can try booting in single user/recovery mode, by modifying boot options, so that you stop booting at early stage, when root filesystem is checked. It is then mounted read only. If you are able to run `dd` at that stage, you may want to achieve what you need. Other than that, I see no option. Usually this is done by booting from external devices.

Comment: @raj this looks to me as a valid way. Unfortunately when booting with single user and then dropping down to a root shell, I see the filesystem has been already remounted `rw`, and even killing all processes but kernel's and the current bash, the mount point `/` remain `busy` to be remounted `ro`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't umount the root partition. Doing so will takes you to a system where you can't open files, detect new hardware or even remounting the root partition again. At this point, your system doesn't know what /dev means and you can only shootdown and reboot.

In order to dd your root partition, if you can't boot from external devices, I'm afraid you're almost out of aces. Could you try to attach your HDD/SDD to another system?.

Sure you can umount the root partition just for fun, but **DON'T mess around with this**:

```
# umount -lf /
```

Comment: You identified a very good point; if there is no `/` there is not even `/usr/bin/dd`. So I really need to have it (re)mounted read-only. I can't physically detach my nvme